# html li animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frameworks

I want to replicate an effect I saw in a recent web template ([here](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_43437/#!/page_find) is the link). in this template when you click a link on the menubar it's content appear in some sort of background position change. Is there any kind of framework to do these kind of templates? and how do they do it, any references?

Many Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I googled alot and didn't come up with anything. There are so many demo out there for image or other content animation. but i didn't see anything regarding with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they use this plugin :

http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html

Looking at the source of their page reveals:

```
include('js/jquery.easing.js');
include('js/jquery.backgroundpos.min.js');
include('js/superfish.js');
include('js/switcher.js');
include('js/forms.js');
include('js/googleMap.js');
include('js/jquery.mousewheel.js');
include('js/uScroll.js');
include('js/jquery.color.js');
include('js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js');
include("js/preloadIMG.js");
include('js/MathUtils.js');
include('js/jquery.transform-0.9.3.min.js');
include('js/bg.js');
```

Comment: Yes i saw it. but have to dig around little bit more. I'll mark your answer correct if i haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question How they do it ??

In chrome if you inspect any of the menu element you will see that they are using two "divs" in a "li" element with different css on them and when you move the mouse they change the position of the divs (the top attribute in the style). I have a sample implementation of the behavior in this fiddle. Though I am not sure which plugin they are using. I will try to find it out

http://jsfiddle.net/CQs7Q/1/

The HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="first">Settings</div>
        <div class="second">Settings</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $("li div.first").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({"top":-20})
        $(this).next(".second").animate({"top":-20})
        //$(this).css("top","-20px").next(".second").css("top","-20px");
    })
    $("li div.second").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({"top":0})
        $(this).prev(".first").animate({"top":0})

    })
})
```

CSS

```
ul {
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    list-style:none;
    height:20px;
}

ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
ul li div {
    position:relative;
    height:20px;
}
ul li div.first {
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}
```

Hope it helps !